# Setting a date range to retrieve users logging in, end up with 1970-01-01

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Here is the whole code. I'm including the whole thing because I can't tell which part causes the dates to set to 1970-01-01.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>...</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="icon" href="images/opacIcon.ico" />
</head>
<body id="home">
<div id="date">
    <? 
        date_default_timezone_set('.../...');
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        echo "Today is $today";
    ?><br>

</div>
<div id="logoTop">
    <img src = "images/....png" alt = "... logo here" width="355" />
</div>
<FORM method="post" id="form" action="Home.php">
    <input type="submit" id="logoutBtn" name="submit" value="Home" style="cursor: pointer;"/><br>
</FORM>
<FORM method="post" id="form" action="Logout.php">
    <input type="submit" id="logoutBtn" name="submit" value="Log Out" style="cursor: pointer;"/><br>
</FORM>

<div style="position: absolute; left:10em; top: 0em;">
    <ul id="nav">
       <li><a href="SysUsers.php">By Date</a></li>
       <li><a href="UsersTableCourse.php">By Course</a></li>
       <li><a href="UsersTableYr.php">By Year</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="search">
       <div class="DropD">
          <form method="post">
             <select name="SYr">
                <option value="">Please Select...</option>
                <option value="1">First Year</option>
                <option value="2">Second Year</option>
                <option value="3">Third Year</option>
                <option value="4">Fourth Year</option>
                <option value="5">Fifth Year</option>
             </select>
             <input type="submit" id="Sbtn1" style="cursor: pointer;" name="search_projects" value="Search">
          </form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="DDate">
      <form method="post">
          <input type="date" name="Date1" value="<?php echo $_POST['Date1'] ?>"  style="position:absolute; top:2em; left:7em;">
          <p style="font-family:Calibri; color:green; font-size:15px; position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 18em;">to</p>
          <input type="date" name="Date2" value="<?php echo $_POST['Date2'] ?>" style="position:absolute; top:2em; left:23em;"><br />
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="scrollableTable">
   <center><table class="font1" border="3px solid white" width="70%">
      <thead> 
          <tr id="tblRow">
         <th id="tblData" width="20%">Access Date</td>
         <th id="tblData" width="15%">ID number</td>
             <th id="tblData" width="35%">Name</td>
         <th id="tblData" width="20%">Keyword</td>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <?php
         if ( $_POST['search_projects'] ) {
            $SYr = $_POST['SYr'];
            $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['Date1'] ) );
            $endDate   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['Date2'] ) );

            $con = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error() ); 
            mysql_select_db("...");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE SYear LIKE '$SYr' AND (accessDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate') ORDER BY accessDate DESC";
            $result = mysql_query( $sql );
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) { 
               $Date = $row->accessDate; 
               $ID = $row->IDnum;
               $Name = $row->Sname; 
               $Key = $row->keyWord;
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $Date.  " </td>" . " <td>" . $ID.  " </td>" . " <td>" . $Name.  " </td>". " <td>" . $Key.  " </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</center>";
    }
 ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried removing the part where the user is asked to set the date ranges and I get the right results which includes the users who logged in as 4th year students. Then I added the date ranges to limit the results and I get nothing. I echoed the dates and found out they were set on the Unix epoch date which is "1970-01-01". How can I stop this from happening? Is it with the conversion. Please don't mind the obviousness of my code being open to sql injection. I just need to get the right results for now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because strtotime() returns FALSE, which is then interpreted as 0 by the date() function. Make sure the dates are entered in a format which can be unambiguously parsed by the strtotime() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php